# If y=f(x̄), in which x̄ is the mean of xi, how can I calculate the minimum number of x samples to obtain y with 95% confidence and 10% error?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample

I am able to calculate the minimum number of samples of x based on the standard deviation of x and the assumption of normal distribution using the standard equation. However, I need to know what that means for y and how I can calculate the minimum number of samples based on the error and confidence interval of y which I am interested in.

Comment: This looks like a modification of your original question, James.  Until that question receives an answer, please feel free to edit it if you wish to modify or improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the note. How can I delete my former question? I think I'm more clear in this one.

Comment: Don't delete it--just edit it.